# How to count the numer of mentions of words from a column?

Tags: python, counter, sentiment-analysis, review

I'm trying to count how many times a word is mentioned in the column `tokenized` in the file `reviews_english`.

The column `tokenized` looks as follows `{restaurant, Juni, 2019, Arrogante, service, ..}`. With my current code I get the following error message

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
counts = collections.Counter(reviews_english['tokenized'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The column `tokenized` appears to be of type `set`. This is problematic not only because (as the error states) sets are not hashable, but also because sets do not contain duplicates, and so all of the words will appear in the set only once. If you're able to make `tokenized` into a list *before* it is populated, there can be duplicate values and therefore words can show up multiple times.